# How to change password for connecting to Wi-Fi network?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, passwords

[image]

The white text means `Can't connect to the network`. It's because it uses a wrong password. How to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the network and click Forget.

When connecting, specify the right password.